# Can you travel to Northern Cyprus without a Turkish visa?

Tags: transit, transit-visas, turkey, filipino-citizens, cyprus

I am a Philippines citizen, holding an ordinary passport, and I'm married to an American. We will be going to Northern Cyprus (KKTC/TRNC). I can get a visa for Northern Cyprus at the airport.

However, it seems that I need a transit visa or entry visa to Turkey, since we will have to leave the international terminal and take a domestic flight to Cyprus.

Any ideas how and whom to ask for this, since the e-Visa specifies Schengen visa holders need to be issued one. Technically, we are not going to Turkey, rather to Northern Cyprus. Any information is much appreciated.

Comment: You question is flawed.  Flights to Northern Cyprus depart from the International terminal in Turkey.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, the Turkish Airlines website noted that there's a need for a visa because the terminal change. Could it be wrong then? What do you suggest?

Comment: Picking a flight at random, yesterdays TK962 to Ercan departed from gate 201, which is in the international terminal.

Comment: Also, if you have a US visa (which I'm guessing you may given you are married to an American) then you can get a visa on arrival ($30) or an e-visa in advance ($20). It's not needed, but at least it gives a backup plan.

Answer (score 1):

Flights to Northern Cyprus depart from the international terminal so you can go ahead and fly via Turkey. Enjoy your trip.